# django database connection error with sql 2003

Tags: django

Am using django 1.3.3
python 2.7
django-mssql = 1.2
Am tryin to connect to sql2003.

Am getting the following exception:

Caught OperationalError while rendering: (com_error(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft SQL Server Native Client ClientName', u'The requested properties cannot be supported.', None, 0, -2147217887), None), 'Error opening connection: DATA SOURCE=host;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;UID=userid;PWD=password;PROVIDER=SQLNCLI10;MARS Connection=True;DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True;')

Is there any extra stuff that am supposed to install

Comment: django-mssql only claims to support SQL Server 2005, 2008 and 2008rc2.

Comment: oh so isnt there any way through which I can connect to sql2003?